# SQL Query master detail style

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a php+jquery phone app. The dificulty I am having is with the SQL database calls. I have successfully connected to the Joomla Database. I have retrieved simple information, such as a list of tables. What I want to do, and what I am needing: a list of of data from a specific catagory..(jos_content) that will be restrained by a section id, and a state.

```
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `jos_content` WHERE state=1 and sectionid=6");
```

this works. This returns a small list that I can sort and filter to get the most recent article entry. BUT, I want to display another select statement when this entry is selected. I have it where it navigates to another page, but how do I relate the 2 statements?

So, you get a list *(list of 1 item)* that is a featured article. Then clicking on it brings you to the article. and will display the img, text and author and date.

Any help would be awesome. I am just learning this SQL database stuff slowly.

Best,
 Corey

Comment: You can't really associate two queries together.  You can, however, pass your second query a value from the first one (your selected record) and then run your second query that will need to be built with the tables on the first query included.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what you mean by "I want to display another select statement when this entry is selected".  If I understand you correctly, you'll need to use the columns your retrieved from the SELECT statement you've shown to construct a URL

Comment: right, but where and how do I setup and code for the the subsequent query for the "products" from a "category" table. Lets say there are 3 categories. How does it know what category was selected where I have a second select stmt showing the products. follow me now?

Comment: Assuming you have a page with something like a list box, or a link with that category, you would include that selection in the querystring to the next page - something like "index.php?selectedCategory=123....".  When the next page is loaded, it can then be retrieved with "$cat = $_GET['selectedCategory'] , and then used in the construction of the 2nd SQL statement for the 2nd php page to use and display.

Comment: got it. ive got that down. when i hoverr over the link it displays the proper category from the db, first stmt. so i need to add that category id to the construction of the second query that will display that specific item.

Comment: Correct....to see what I mean, put this at the top of that 2nd php page:  echo "<pre>".print_r($_GET,true)."</pre>";  You'll be able to see what is being passed to that page, and go from there.

Comment: thanks Greg! I am back at work today, going to give your sugestions a go, and look at what is being passed back and forth.